# Working with svg in android

Tags: android, graphics

I do not know the proper usage of svg images and shapes in android .
but actually my problem is : i want to use an svg images as a background of a component that i mentioned in xml , and want to bind a svg picture in onCreate() to a editText for example .
i ve seen how can take it for Layout but dont know what about editText.
and after i use this code( below) , the svg image could not be scaleble and resize for a background image . the size remain in default .

```
     mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.content);
     SVG svg=SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notepad);
     Drawable picDrawable=svg.createPictureDrawable();
    mBodyText.setBackgroundDrawable(picDrawable);
```

also i use the Draw method and still nothing .

thanks to everyone read